# Am I using StreamReader inefficiently? - 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting this error when I write to a file and replace strings contained within the file and I've no idea how to solve it:

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\WarThunder\config.blk' because it is being used by another process.

I've tried closing everything I have open that could host this files data, but I have a feeling that it's probably my inefficient use of code causing this. It wasn't a problem before. I don't remember when it cropped up :/

The following code is repeated one time each for the other two checkboxes:

```
private void rdbDX11_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rdbDX11.Checked == true)
        {
            pbOGL3Outer.Visible = false;
            pdDX11Outer.Visible = true;
            pdDX9Outer.Visible = false;
            rdbDX9.Checked = false;
            rdbOGL3.Checked = false;
            Properties.Settings.Default.varRenderSelected = ("DirectX11");

            using (StreamReader ReadConfig = new StreamReader(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig))
            {
                while (ReadConfig.Peek() != 1)                              //While not end of file
                {
                    var ReWriteFile = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig);

                    if (ReWriteFile.Contains("  driver:t=\"dx9\""))
                    { ReWriteFile = ReWriteFile.Replace("  driver:t=\"dx9\"", "  driver:t=\"dx11\""); }

                    else if (ReWriteFile.Contains("  driver:t=\"gl3\""))
                    { ReWriteFile = ReWriteFile.Replace("  driver:t=\"gl3\"", "  driver:t=\"dx11\""); }

                    else if (ReWriteFile.Contains("  driver:t=\"auto\""))
                    { ReWriteFile = ReWriteFile.Replace("  driver:t=\"auto\"", "  driver:t=\"dx11\""); }

                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig, ReWriteFile);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Read the entire text `var ReWriteFile = File.ReadAllText` edit it then write it: `File.WriteAllText(...`. Do not use `StreamReader` at all

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is

1. Read the text from the file
2. Edit the text
3. Write it back to the file

something like this:

```
private void rdbDX11_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdbDX11.Checked == true)
    {
        pbOGL3Outer.Visible = false;
        pdDX11Outer.Visible = true;
        pdDX9Outer.Visible = false;
        rdbDX9.Checked = false;
        rdbOGL3.Checked = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.varRenderSelected = ("DirectX11");

        // Read
        var ReWriteFile = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig);

        // Edit
        ReWriteFile = ReWriteFile
          .Replace("  driver:t=\"dx9\"", "  driver:t=\"dx11\"") 
          .Replace("  driver:t=\"gl3\"", "  driver:t=\"dx11\"")
          .Replace("  driver:t=\"auto\"", "  driver:t=\"dx11\"");

        // Write back
        File.WriteAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig, ReWriteFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig, ReWriteFile);
```

is unable to write to `Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig` because you have an open `StreamWriter` to the same file, which you open in your `using` statement:

```
using (StreamReader ReadConfig = new StreamReader(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig))
```

There is no reason to even create this `StreamReader` or use a `while` loop.  You are reading the full text of the file with this line:

```
var ReWriteFile = File.ReadAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.SavedConfig);
```

Lose the `using` block; lose the `while` loop.  All better.